# api v3 weather layer is showing m/s but I want mph

Tags: google-maps

Using code below.. weather shows m/s (meters/sec) but I want mph

snip:

```
var weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
    windSpeedUnit: google.maps.weather.WindSpeedUnit.MILES_PER_HOUR,
    temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT
  });
  weatherLayer.setMap(map);
```

Question: is this a bug?.. or am I doing something wrong?

thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has to be `windSpeedUnits` (the 's' at the end is missing)

Comment: Good catch, and to the OP: check this out https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#WeatherLayer

Comment: That was it. Thank you... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#WeatherLayerOptions